# HTML5 Flash 100% IE8 and Firefox

Tags: html

I need to have a flash intro for my website (a requirement from my teacher). I created the intro and embedded it into my page. I takes up the entire screen in both Chrome and Chromium. In IE8, Firefox and Opera the size is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3; url=template.htm">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Com Tech Projects | Jason Cook</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background: black;">
        <embed style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="Flash/Introv6.swf"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - You are using Flash. :P

Comment: I know. She seems to be convinced that Flash is a necessary skill to have. She does not seem to know about the new HTML5 features. The rest of the class did their site in Dreamweaver and Fireworks. My website will probably be the only site that is standards compliment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
<style>
html,body{height:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;background-color:black;}
</style>
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

In the HTML5 doctype, the parent element must also have % values defined for a child element to use % values.  So in the CSS for your body tag:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I changed my body tag to "<body style="background: black; height: 100%; width: 100%;">" and am still having the same problem in Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fullscreen, write the following:

```
<video style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
   <embed style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;"  src="Flash/Introv6.swf"/>
</video>
```

If that does not work, consider the use of the `<object>` tag instead of `<embed>`.